# How to build Docker image own image

Tags: windows, docker

Currently I'm doing POC in docker for Windows 2016.  I just want to know how to build an own image.

Currently we are using

```
docker pull microsoft/windowsservercore
```

to pull base image but due to security reason we should not download images from public repository. So we should build our own Windows images.

Is it possible to build our own image with out downloading? If yes, means how we can build our own Windows server images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to build a base image you can use `tar` or `scratch`

Below is the example:

```
FROM scratch
ADD helloworld.sh /usr/local/bin/hellowworld.sh
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/helloworld.sh"]
```

see the [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/) to get more information

Comment: yes, i can do. but for windows is there any reference available so that i can build my own images. without downloading.  i can't fine any reference.  Let me know if you have

Answer (score 0):

I think you've to setup your own company docker registry. After setting it up you can "import" the `windowsservercore` image to the private registry. See this [link](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#stop-a-local-registry) for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one downloaded image as the base image and then customize that image as per your needs. You should refer to [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) for information regarding configuring your own image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. yes i can use base image.  But i just want to know is there any way i can build my own base image. without downloading or external image

Comment: Yeah, you can build from [scratch](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/#creating-a-simple-parent-image-using-scratch)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Is there any reference  for windows server core.  so that it will be really helpful to me

Comment: I am not sure if you are looking for [iis](https://github.com/Microsoft/iis-docker) server image. If this is not you want, I am looking for windows server core.

Comment: [Is there a windows docker image](https://stefanscherer.github.io/is-there-a-windows-docker-image-for/) would also not help, but I am adding it for info. And I don't think microsoft has released any dockerfile or something for windows server core.